# How to inject script using node.js code?

Tags: node.js, browser, code-injection

You all know open npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/open
Using this package, one can write the following code:

```
var open = require('./node_modules/open/lib/open.js')
open('http://www.cnn.com')
```

and activating it by:

```
$ node app.js
```

will open a browser window of cnn.com.

I want my script to open this site and inject some code to the console. I mean that the browser will behave like I clicked F12, went to 'console' tab and typed in console the code:

```
alert('Hello World')
```

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I don't think this is possible for obvious security purposes

Comment: why? If I can open the browser, enter to "www.cnn.com", click F12 and type "alert('hello world')" in console, why can't I write code that does it? Where is the security concern here?

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239827/how-to-inject-script-using-node-js-code/45241731#45241731) below help you? Any comments?

Comment: I promise that I'll read it carefully later. I didn't have the time so far. If it's what I needed, I'll mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `open` module is used to "Open a file or url in the user's preferred application."

It can open the preferred application (a browser in this case) but it cannot control it. In fact, it doesn't even know what browser will that be (or even if that will be a browser).

What you are asking for can be achieved with tools like PhantomJS ("PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API."), Nightmare.js ("A high-level browser automation library.") or CasperJS ("Navigation scripting & testing for PhantomJS and SlimerJS"), see:

- http://phantomjs.org/
- http://www.nightmarejs.org/
- http://casperjs.org/

Comment: 1. when you say that "phantomjs" is "headless", does it mean that no browser is actually opened and that all operations are taking place "behind the scene"?
2. can nightmare.js be used in order to make a browser open and see in it the website visually ?
3. It will be really helpful if you can write some code that inject script to developer tools.